# How does Giant Sand Worm work with Windfury?

Tags: hearthstone

If I somehow give Windfury to this pretty boy

[image]

(for example by getting [Windfury](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/146-windfury) from an enemy mage playing a [Spellslinger](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/22299-spellslinger)), what is going to happen if I kill one of the opponent's minions? Do I get two more attacks? Or is the additional attack from Windfury wasted in this case?

Comment: My guess would be it just adds another 'normal' attack, so windfury would just be pushed back. Interesting question for science, though

Comment: @twobugs definitely doing it for science, the chance of this happening is VERY low, but it still could be an interesting interaction

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It can attack the opposing hero twice and any number of minions before. (As long as it kills them.)
I tested this in a practice game via Enhance-o Mechano.

Before attacks:
[image]

After first (minion) and second attack (hero): 
[image]

After third (minion) and fourth attack (hero):
[image]

Comment: So potentially it could "double tap" an opposing big minion to kill it, then keep attacking afterwards. Thanks for testing this out!

Comment: After it killed a minion with it's 3rd attack shouldn't it of chained into a 5th attack? Since the card says "whenever it attacks and kills a minion". The order of chaining seemed to be going `base` -> `windfury` -> `bonus base` -> `windfury`. Even in the situation where it goes `base` -> `bonus base` -> `windfury` -> `bonus base`, it seems like that last bonus base should of triggered another windfury.

Comment: This wasn't on the wiki, so I added it as a reference. Thanks! https://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Giant_Sand_Worm#Notes